# Perl Image Gallery Issue

Tags: perl

I'm trying to build an image gallery. I'm using Perl to grab a list of images in a directory and display them. The images are all different heights and widths. The script will grab the image names, find the width and height of each, and display them on the page, along with the rest of the HTML for the page. My images are 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg... up to 15 (for now, many many more will be added later).

My issue is when I need the script to generate the image name, it stops getting the image's dimensions. If I hard code the image, it works and tells me the dimensions.

Here's what I have (I know this might be rough...)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Image::Magick;
my $magick = Image::Magick->new;

opendir(DIR, "./images/");
@images = readdir(DIR);
close(DIR);

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

foreach $file (@images) {
    $magick->Read( './images/$file' );
    my $width  = $magick->Get('width');
    my $height = $magick->Get('height');
    print "<img src=\"images/$file\" width=\"$width\" height=\"$height\">\n";
}
```

If I change `$magick->Read( './images/$file' );` to `$magick->Read( './images/1.jpg' );` it works. Of course, it then shows 1.jpg 15 times, but it is able to display the width and height. Any ideas why this is? I assume I just missed something, but I've been working on this all day.

Thank you.

Comment: Create a new empty directory and call `readdir` on it. You might be surprised by the results. `mkdir foo && perl -wE 'opendir my $dh, "foo" or die $!; say for readdir $dh'` outputs `..` and `.` You probably don't want to treat those as images.

Comment: Also, you should add `use strict; use warnings;` to the top of every Perl script you write, since it can help catch a lot of common errors (although it wouldn't have helped in this particular case).

Comment: Sorry, perl, not PERL. I do know that it outputs .. and . but I figure I can get around that later.

Answer (score 3):

Your main issue is that single quoted strings do not interpolate variables. You are looking for an image with the filename `$image` and not using the value of the variable `$image`.

Use `"` instead of `'`

---

Additionally, you aren't doing anything to check that the the filenames actually represent images or url encoding the names when you turn them into URLs for the HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. 

@Quentin
Ok, the `'` to `"` worked, somewhat. Now it shows a height and width, but it only shows the height and width of the first image. So if 1.jpg is 100x100 and 2.jpg is 300x200, it now displays both images 100x100.

Comment: @Squalle When you call `Read` multiple times on the same `Image::Magick` object, you read the images into an image sequence. To access the other images in the sequence, you need to access them by their index, i.e. `$image->[1]->Get('width')` would give the width of the 2nd image in the sequence. Note that each image in a sequence is stored in memory, which can eat up a sizable chunk of RAM. Consider creating a new object for each image and destroying when you're done with it as described in the [overview section of the documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php#overview).

Answer (score 1):

As has been explained, `readdir` will return both file and directory names, as well as the pseudo-directories `.` and `..`. You also have a problem with appending the file name to the directory name.

It is best to use `File::Spec` to manipulate file paths, so as to avoid any mistakes of this sort, and you should use the `-f` file test to discard all directory names.

Here's an example

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

use File::Spec::Functions qw/ catfile /;
use Image::Magick;

my $dir = 'images';

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

opendir my ($dh), $dir;

while (my $node = readdir $dh) {

    my $file = catfile($dir, $node);
    next unless -f $file;

    my $magick = Image::Magick->new;
    $magick->Read($file);
    my $width  = $magick->Get('width');
    my $height = $magick->Get('height');

    print qq{<img src="$file" width="$width" height="$height">\n};
}
```

Comment: @Squalle Note the `use autodie;` at the top of this example script, which will cause the script to die if `opendir` fails. You should be checking whether `opendir` succeeds in your script, too, whether manually (e.g. `opendir my $dh, 'foo' or die "Failed to opendir: $!"`) or with `autodie`.